# Api-Platform 3: DataTransformerInterface Issue

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony6

I am learning to create DTO and DataTransformerInterface to send specific data in my response.

The issue is that the file "DataTransformerInterface" is missing.
When I checked the "Api-Platform" folder, the Core folder is missing and when I verified on the git repository, the core folder is not available there.

I have searched through vendor and the file could not be found.

Did anybody run into this problem and manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no more `DataTransformerInterface` in API-Platform 3.
You should implement your logic inside a `stateProvider` or a `stateProcessor` instead.

Look at [this](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/upgrade-guide/#datatransformers-and-dto-support).